# Linq to SQL datacontext not updating for foreign key relationships

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, foreign-keys

I'm writing a database test against a repository that uses L2S.  In my database I have a `Manifest` entity and an `AllocatedTransaction` entity.  The AllocatedTransaction entity has a foreign key to the Manifest's id.  The DDL looks something like this:

```
Manifest:
Id - int - identity

AllocateTransaction:
Id - int - identity
Quantity - int
ManifestId - FK to Manifest
```

In my test, I'm checking to see if AllocatedTransactions are coming back with the Manifest.  The test looks like this:

```
[TestMethod]
public void FindByIdTest()
{
    using (data.EZTracDataContext dataContext = new data.EZTracDataContext())
    {
        using (new TransactionScope())
        {
            data.Manifest manifest = _testDataProvider.AddManifest(dataContext);

            data.AllocatedTransaction allocatedTransaction = _testDataProvider.AddEligibilityAllocated(dataContext, 5, manifest.Id);

            ManifestRepository repository = CreateRepository(dataContext);

            var actual = repository.FindById(manifest.Id).AllocatedTransactions;
            var expected = new[] { new domain.AllocatedTransaction(allocatedTransaction.Id, 5, manifest.Id) }.ToList();

            CollectionAssertAreEqual(actual, expected);
        }
    }
}
```

The `_testDataProvider` just adds records to the database using the passed in `dataContext`.  The `FindById` method looks like this:

```
public domain.Manifest FindById(int id)
{
    var persistedManifest = GetPersistedManifest(id);
    var requestedManifest = GetDomainManifestFromData(persistedManifest);
    return requestedManifest;
}

private Manifest GetPersistedManifest(int manifestId)
{
    return (from manifests in DataContext.Manifests
            where manifests.Id == manifestId
            select manifests).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

My problem is the Manifest entity coming back from the DataContext does not have the AllocateTransaction associated to it.  The strange thing is pre-existing Manifests ***do*** come back with their AllocatedTransactions attached.  Could using the same DataContext object for inserting the records and retrieving the records be causing this?  Is this a bug with L2S?

Comment: Does the `_testDataProvider` call `SaveChanges()` on the `DataContext`, such that the `Manifest` and `AllocatedTransaction` are getting their unique IDs? What happens if you attach a new `Manifest` to the `AllocatedTransaction` and then persist the `AllocatedTransation`?

Comment: `SubmitChanges()` is being called from the `_testDataProvider` and the `Manifest` and `AllocatedTransaction` are getting their IDs.  Currently I am just attaching the unique id from the `Manifest` when persisting the `AllocatedTransaction`.  I just tried attaching the entire `Manifest` and to the `AllocatedTransaction`, like you suggested, but got the same result.

Comment: Jay, I think you have it backwards.  Based on the code sample, Manifest is the parent entity and AllocatedTransaction is the child entity.  You need to attach the AllocatedTransaction to the Manifest, not the other way around.

Comment: JChristian, you can't simply attach the ID when trying to resolve a foreign key relationship in LINQ-to-SQL. You have to attach the entire entity object to avoid adding an INSERT to the DataContext's ChangeSet.  See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question, is this what you're trying to do?

```
using (new TransactionScope())
{
    Manifest manifest = new Manifest
    {
        AllocatedTransactions.Add(new AllocatedTransaction
        {
            Quantity = 5
        }
    };

    DataContext.Manifests.InsertOnSubmit(manifest);
    DataContext.SubmitChanges();

    Manifest newManifest = DataContext.Manifests.Where(a => a.ID == manifest.ID).SingleOrDefault(); 

    Assert.AreEqual(manifest.AllocatedTransactions.First().Quantity, newManifest.AllocatedTransactions.First().Quantity);
}
```

You also don't need to manually retrieve the AllocatedTransaction entities associated with the Manifest.  Just retrieve the `Manifest` entity as I did with the `newManifest` object and all the associated `AllocatedTransaction` entities should follow along.

**UPDATE:**

It looks like you're trying to attach in the wrong direction. You need to attach the AllocatedTransaction to the Manifest, not the other way around:

```
Manifest manifest = DataContext.Manifests.Single(a => a.ID == 27);
AllocatedTransaction allTrans = DataContext.AllocatedTransactions.Single(a => a.ID == 53);

manifest.AllocatedTransactions.Add(allTrans);
DataContext.SubmitChanges();
```

This assumes that both the Manifest and AllocatedTransaction records already exist. I would highly recommend that you **not* prepopulate the `ManifestID` field in the AllocatedTransactions object. If you add it as I have demonstrated above, the LINQ engine will automatically resolve and update the foreign key value. If you set the value ahead of time, it may throw off the ChangeSet and assume that you are trying to add a new record rather than attach an existing one.

Comment: Essentially that is what I'm trying to do, but I'm not creating/submitting the `Manifest` and 'AllocatedTransactions' at the same time.  I'm first creating the `Manifest`, submitting it, and then I'm creating and submitting `AllocatedTransaction` using the `ManifestId` from the existing `Manifest`.  I tried creating the 'AllocatedTransaction' and attaching a `Manifest` to it, then submitting, as suggested in the comments by @Jon, with no luck.